# Liferay 7: hidden aui input won't set value based on parameter

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-aui, liferay-service-builder

I have an entity with a primary key and two other fields.
I am able to display them in a Search Container in my primary View JSP, and I want to implement an edit/update function, so I created a different JSP for that. I pass the properties of the entity I wish to edit in ***portlet:renderURL*** ***portlet:param*** tags just like this:

```
<portlet:renderURL var="editEntity">
    <portlet:param name="jspPage" value="/update-page.jsp" /> 
    <portlet:param name="primaryKey" value="<%= entityId %>" /> 
    <portlet:param name="name" value="<%= entityName%>" /> 
    <portlet:param name="description" value="<%= entityDesc%>" /> 
</portlet:renderURL>
```

In the update-page JSP if I set *any* input field hidden, the parameter based values disappear, so the controller cannot process the fields' values.

i.e.:

```
<aui:input name="primaryKey" type="hidden" value="${primaryKey}" />
<aui:input name="primaryKey" type="hidden" value="${name}" />
<aui:input name="primaryKey" type="hidden" value="${description}" />
```

Note: I only want to hide the primary key field, the controller servlet should be able to process it and update my entity based on the primary key, like this:

```
<aui:input name="primaryKey" type="text" value="${name}" />
<aui:input name="primaryKey" type="text" value="${description}" />
```

The funny thing is, that everything just works when I set the input fields text type, but I wouldn't want the users to enter the primary key, duh...

Any ideas how could I fix this?

Comment: is this inside <aui:form> ?

Comment: Of course. I don't know why it isn't working properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to the problem.

So, after long hours of testing I found out that I just could not get the values stored in parameters just as **${paramName}** anywhere in a simple HTML tag, but I still don't know why.

What I did was request for the needed values stored within the parameters inside a JSP scriptlet just like this:

```
<% 
String primaryKey = request.getParameter("primaryKey");
String name = request.getParameter("name");
String description = request.getParameter("description");
%>
```

Then I was good to go with my form:

```
<aui:form action="<%= updateAbbreviationURL %>" method="post">
    <aui:input name="primaryKey" type="hidden" value="<%= primaryKey %>" />
    <aui:input name="entityName" label="Name" type="text" value="<%= name %>" />
    <aui:input name="entityDesc" label="Description" type="text" value="<%= description %>" />
    <aui:button name="submit" value="submit" type="submit" />
    <aui:button name="cancel" value="cancel" type="button" onClick="<%= viewURL %>" />          
</aui:form>
```

I'd be really grateful if someone told me why my initial implementation didn't work, I mean referring to the parameter values as mentioned above, ${paramName}

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It's work for me

**view.jsp**

```
<%@ include file="init.jsp" %>
<portlet:actionURL name="testURL" var="testURL" />
<aui:form name="fm" method="post" action="<%= testURL.toString()%>">
 <aui:input name="primaryKey" type="hidden" value="123" />
 <aui:button-row>
        <aui:button name="submit" type="submit" value="OK"  />
    </aui:button-row>  
</aui:form>
```

**TestmvcportletPortlet.java**

```
package com.example.portlet;

import com.liferay.portal.kernel.exception.SystemException;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.portlet.bridges.mvc.MVCPortlet;
import com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ParamUtil;

import javax.portlet.ActionRequest;
import javax.portlet.ActionResponse;
import javax.portlet.Portlet;
import javax.portlet.ProcessAction;

import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;

@Component(
 immediate = true,
 property = {
  "com.liferay.portlet.display-category=category.sample",
  "com.liferay.portlet.instanceable=true",
  "javax.portlet.display-name=Test Portlet",
  "javax.portlet.init-param.template-path=/",
  "javax.portlet.init-param.view-template=/view.jsp",
  "javax.portlet.resource-bundle=content.Language",
  "javax.portlet.security-role-ref=power-user,user"
 },
 service = Portlet.class
)
public class TestmvcportletPortlet extends MVCPortlet {

 @ProcessAction(name = "testURL")
    public void addBook(ActionRequest actionRequest,ActionResponse actionResponse) throws SystemException {
      String a = ParamUtil.getString(actionRequest, "primaryKey");
      System.out.println("Value is "+a);

    }
}
```

have you found anything that you missed code?

Comment: Sorry, I probably wasn't too clear. My problem is with parameter based values. I'll edit my post to clarify